# How can I use a component that was defined in my core module from a lazy route?

Tags: angular, angular2-modules

I have a component that I would like to reuse in a few places throughout my applications. As such, I created a module within my core module with new component. The error I'm getting is `'foo' is not a known element`.

You can see a demo [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/xncP7eAGMEaK3XWV9nDk?p=preview). You will see the component I wish to share module in `app/core/foo/foo.component.ts`, which has been imported into `CoreModule`. And you will see `FooComponent` (using selector `foo`) being used in `app/crisis/crisis-list.component.ts`.

I've read the Angular 2 module documentation to death and can't put my finger on why I can't use `FooComponent` wherever I please.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import `FooModule` in `CrisisModule` like that;

```
import { FooModule } from '../core/foo/foo.component';
...
@NgModule({
     imports: [CommonModule, CrisisRoutingModule, FooModule],
     ...
})
export class CrisisModule{}
```

Whenever you want to use any component, just import the module which includes declaration of component.

Answer (score 1):

You have to choice  :

1- Import  your module in the module that is going to use it

2- Declare the component (not the module ) in the module that your going to use it.

BUT :

Module approach is better , because if you have a module inside another module , you cannot declare your component in both of them , but you can import the module in both of them :!

Comment: I remember thinking this but thought the point of `CoreModule` was that everything in there was freely accessible to the entire application.

Comment: That would only work if you import CoreModule in every single Module :)

Answer (score 1):

To make common component working in various module, you have to `export` that `Component` from particular module by specifying `exports` option of `NgModule` like below, so that will be act as shareable `Component`

```
exports: [CommonComponent] //it will contain the list of shareable Components
```

and then inject that module inside the another module wherever you want to use Common Component.

> **NOTE:** Even you had mentioned `CommonComponent` to be there inside `declartions` option of module, it will not allow to use those `Component`s , `Pipe`'s, `Directive`'s in other module directly, to make it work you have to export specific component which should work as shareable.

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought that simply exporting it from `FooModule`, then importing and exporting that module in `CoreModule` that it would be made available to the entire application.